# Printing long pic from screen capture

Tags: printing

I used android13 screen capture to scroll down so I have a very long pic now. How can I print this pic across multiple pages, each page having a zoomed in portion of the overall pic, since the only way I can see to print it at the moment, prints a portion of the overall pic, but the printout only shows page 1 of 1 when there would be many pages in total?

This is for Facebook comments, the phone will not print them properly either if I just select share/print from the options within the Facebook app.
I have had to go to my computer and print out all comments using it.

Thank you.

Comment: There are apps that support "poster printing" which actually means splitting a large image onto multiple pages. I would try apps like https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.caomobile.photosplit (have not tries it myself).